# remove function for list iterator does not seem to remove items

Tags: java, listiterator

I'm working on a web crawler and part of the functionality I'm trying to build in is that it pulls links when parsing a page and removes duplicate ones.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;    
import com.bal.Link;
import com.bal.WebPage;

public class webCrawlerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        WebPage wp = null;
        int numberOfLoopsThroughLinks = 22;
        ArrayList<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();
        links.add(new Link("http://jsoup.org/"));
        ArrayList<Link> foundLinks;
        try{
            for(int i=0; i < numberOfLoopsThroughLinks; i++){

                for(ListIterator<Link> ls = links.listIterator(); ls.hasNext();){//need to use an iterator to avoid a concurrent modification exception
                    Link l = ls.next();
                    if(!l.isVisited()){//if link hasn't been visited
                        l.setVisited(true);
                        System.out.println("Parsing the following URL:"+l.getUrl());
                        wp=new WebPage(l.getUrl());
                        wp.parsePage();
                        foundLinks = wp.getLinks();
                        ArrayList<Link> newLinks = wp.getLinks();
                        newLinks=addToLinks(links, newLinks);
                        for(Link nL: newLinks){                         
                            ls.add(nL);                         
                        }                                                   
                    }                       
                }    
            }               

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Web page url in use at time of exception "+ wp.getUrl());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public static ArrayList<Link> addToLinks(ArrayList<Link> links, ArrayList<Link> newLinks){


        for(ListIterator<Link> iterator = newLinks.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            Link nL = iterator.next();

            for(Link l: links){
                if(nL.getUrl().equals(l.getUrl())){
                    //System.out.println(nL.getUrl()+" == "+l.getUrl());
                    //System.out.println("removed a duplicate link");
                    iterator.remove();
                    if(iterator.hasNext()){
                        iterator.next();
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return newLinks;


    }

}
```

The problem I'm having is I'm getting duplicate prints on the parsing. And since I remove duplicates from the AL to be added and start with only a single link I shouldn't get duplicates added in. And if they are the same element they should be marked as visited and thus shouldn't be visited again.

*It seems that most of the repeating links end with #. If I debug I can see a bunch of links with # and then some extra things i.e http://unicodelookup.com#thai
But those don't seem to ever come up. However if I add one as the first url for that initial link it does display. Is there something weird with the # and strings in Java that doesn't effect pass a string literal as a parameter?

**So I got rid of the ones with the # (apparently Jsoups parser drops things after them since they denote a place on the page and not a distinct href). Still having issues with duplicates.

Comment: I think you need to read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Assuming your `Link` class has overriden the `equals` and `hashcode` method, you could simple use `links.removeAll(newLinks)`

Comment: why not to use Set instead of ArrayList? You will don't have duplicates.

Comment: I'm just more comfortable with an arraylist and I eventually want to switch it to a collection type that searches better and handles parallel/ concurrent operations better.

Answer (score 0):

addToLinks function is moving pointer twice and it is possible that for 2nd move element is duplicated.

First - Move

```
Link nL = iterator.next();
```

Send Move

```
if(iterator.hasNext()){
                    iterator.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used iterators very much.

Comment: It seems I need that second move as if I remove 
if(iterator.hasNext()){
                    iterator.next();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
I get an illegal state exception

Comment: Looks like I needed to use hasPrevious() and previous() in that snippet instead.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm an idiot. Completely forgot it was in a nested loop. Still getting duplicates though. Though fewer since I stopped including ones with # in them and fixed the issue that you pointed out.